# Force table to be as wide as the content needs

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am using HTML-emails to send data tables to clients, but those tables can get pretty wide, at least 2000px. I want that table to take up as much room as it wants, but nothing more than it needs.

edit: I know emails shouldn't be that wide. The problem is that the tables have humongous width and they are supposed to be in the email body. If I leave width on auto, it just gets squished to however wide the container is. I need the tables to be wide enough to be readable, but not wider than necessary. I want the width to be automatically calculated, but not to be restricted by the container width.

Thanks for any answers :)

Comment: HTML emails should be max 600px wide. Even if responsive (unless some strange design in there...). What have you tried? can you explain what means for a table to take space... etc etc?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan see edit

Comment: _"HTML emails should be max 600px wide"_
This is (was) a guideline, rather than a restriction. Emails can be as narrow or wide as they need to be.

Comment: Depends on the design, have some code or a design you're working with?

Comment: @TedGoas It's just some plain text, then that super wide table, and some more plain text.
preferrably I'd like the text to restrict itself to the width of the container, but I want the table to go as far as it needs to, to be humaly readable. I had stuff happen like table headers being squished to the point that there is only one letter per line. I did get it to work acceptably by using inline styling, just for the borders actually. for some reason that made the table wider in most programs I tried looking at the mail in.

Comment: I would still like to know how to force the width properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's just some plain text, then that super wide table, and some more plain text. preferably I'd like the text to restrict itself to the width of the container, but I want the table to go as far as it needs to, to be humanly readable.

In that case, I'd try coding this with *three* email wrappers:

1. A fixed width for the first block of text.
2. An undefined width for the wide table (so it can stretch if need be).
3. A fixed width for the second block of text.

Something like this:

```html
<body width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
    <center style="width: 100%; background: #ffffff; text-align: left;">

        <!-- some plain text : BEGIN -->
        <div style="max-width: 680px; margin: auto;" class="email-container">
            <!--[if mso]>
            <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="680" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]-->
                <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            some plain text
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
        <!-- some plain text : END -->

        <!-- that super wide table : BEGIN -->
        <div style="margin: auto;" class="email-container">
            <!--[if mso]>
            <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]-->
                <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            some plain text
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
        <!-- that super wide table : END -->

        <!-- some more plain text : BEGIN -->
        <div style="max-width: 680px; margin: auto;" class="email-container">
            <!--[if mso]>
            <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="680" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]-->
                <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            some plain more text
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
        <!-- some more plain text : END -->

    </center
</body>
```